# Mysql SELECT priority

Tags: mysql, sql

My database is missing some values:

```
Name   Surname    Country   Salary

John   Walker     USA       800
       Walker     Canada    1000
Peter  Walker     Canada    800
John   Walker               900
Peter  Farmer     USA       1200
...    ...        ...
```

I want to SELECT Name and Surname and Country, if there are no values,
I want to SELECT by Name and Country, if there are no values,
I want to SELECT by Surname and Country.

I am using now:

```
SELECT Salary FROM table_name
WHERE (Name='InputFromPHP' AND Surname='InputFromPHP' AND Country='InputFromPHP')
OR (Name='InputFromPHP' AND Surname='InputFromPHP')
OR (Name='InputFromPHP' AND Country='InputFromPHP')
```

I want to give priority, so it will select exactly what was Input With PHP, but when there are several values in database it gives SQL error.

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Select Salary **From Table_Name** ?

Comment: Yes, I have it I just didnt type it, now Im correcting, sorry :)

Comment: Also you may want to wrap the `AND` chain into a `()` like `Where (Name='something' AND Surname='otherthing') OR (Name='something' AND Surname='otherthing')`

Comment: thank you, but it should work anyway, right ?

Comment: I assume your database maybe case sensitive, you may also want to use upper case column like NAME, SURNAME. Also please provide the error message if any

Comment: @ZayLau There is no error message, everything is working on my website, the only problem is the priority :/ thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT   Salary 
FROM     table_name
WHERE    Name='InputFromPHP'
  AND    (Surname='InputFromPHP' OR Country='InputFromPHP')
ORDER BY CASE Surname WHEN 'InputFromPHP' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
         CASE Country WHEN 'InputFromPHP' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
LIMIT    1
```

Note that your `where` clause always required `Name='InputFromPHP'`, so that can be taken out of the `or` clause.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it's working. :)) Kind regards